# Can you Prove or Disprove this?

Tags: geometry, number-theory

In $a^n+b^n=c^n$ , $(a<b<c)$ , $a,b,n$ belongs to natural numbers,
If $n>=b/2$ , $c$ lies between $(b,b+1)$.

Also, only for $n=1,2$ , $c=b+1$.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, you've said $c$ lies in $(b, b+1)$ but "only for $c = b+1$"?

Comment: @ZainPatel Please read it again. I said for $n=1,2$. I meant, $1+2=3$ and $3^2+4^2=5^2$. Only in these two examples $c=b+1$.

Comment: Back when Fermat's last theorem had been proved for $3 \le n \le 4 \times 10^6$, this showed that any counterexample for larger $n$ would have to involve a number $b^n$ with at least $27$ million decimal digits

Answer (score 1):

To show that $c<b+1$ we must show that $a^n+b^n<(b+1)^n$, for $n\ge b/2$. But $a\le b-1$, so it suffices to prove that 
$$(b-1)^n+b^n<(b+1)^n,\quad \hbox{for}\quad n\ge b/2.$$ 
Dividing by $b^n$ and setting $x=1/b$, that can be written as
$$
(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n>1,\quad\hbox{for}\quad x\ge{1\over2n}.
$$
But that is certainly true if $n\ge3$, because,
$$
(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n=2nx+2{n\choose3}x^3+\ldots>2nx.
$$
For $n=2$ one has $(1+x)^2-(1-x)^2=4x$ and for $n=1$: $(1+x)-(1-x)=2x$, so in such cases for $x=1/(2n)$ the strict inequality does not hold.